# Phantom.js : response body for JSON contentType

Tags: ajax, json, phantomjs, httpresponse

I'm trying to get the body of responses containing JSON in Phantom.js.

From another question I know that around a year and a half ago it wasn't possible :

- Q: [Using phantomjs to read the response body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009881/using-phantomjs-to-read-the-response-body)

After digging a little bit around the Phantom.js's Google Group and GitHub issues I found the following :

- Ticket : [Adding support for getting body of requests or responses](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/pull/11484)
- Pull request : [added response body to response object in onResourceReceived event](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/pull/11484)

Now after reading the pull request messages, especially the last ones, I'm getting confused. It seems that someone wrote the feature and asked for a pull request.

Now I'm running version 1.9.2 and I don't seem to have a "response.body".

```
page.onResourceReceived = function (response) {
    if(response.stage === 'end') {
        var contentType = response.contentType;
        if(contentType && contentType.match(/^(application\/json)/gi)) {
            console.log(response.body); // undefined
        }
    }
};
```

I have the following questions :

- Is the request.body feature implemented yet ?
- If not, when will it be ?
- In the mean time, what are my options ? Should I use the `--proxy=ip:port` option and tunnel every request through a light HTTP server like Express.js ?

Thanks a lot in advance !